# SideBySide Application Error

Tags: windows, visual-c++, tidesdk, side-by-side

I've got an application that has been built with TideSDK.

When trying to run the application on the machine that it was packaged with (runs Windows 8) the application works no problem.  When I try to run this program on a Windows Vista machine that I've got, I get a

**"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail."**

error.

Here's the event viewer information:

**Activation context generation failed for "C:\Users[blah blah blah]\Program.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT, processorArchitecture="x86", publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3", type="win32", version="8.0.50727.4053" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.**

Some solutions say to update windows or reinstall visual c++ redist.

Do these errors signify a needed windows update or visual c++ redist reinstallation?

Thanks in advance!

Vince

Comment: Did you compile the SDK yourself prior to building your app or are you using the SDK download? For this it might be best to file an issue in our issue tracker for followup. https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues

Comment: I should clarify. I d/l'd the TideSDK Developer msi file and used that program to import a project and package it.

Comment: Just for giggles, have you tried installing visual c++ redistributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi The MSVC Redistibutable files are outdated in your system. You need to install "Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1" Redistributables.

they can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14431